# Can I refactor this simple callback pattern that uses the property decorator?

Tags: python, properties, callback, decorator, python-decorators

I'm just getting to grips with decorators in Python and using them to add callbacks to some instance variables using the following simple pattern:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._var = 0
        self.var_callbacks = []

    @property
    def var(self):
        return self._var

    @var.setter
    def var(self, x):
        self._var = x
        for f in self.var_callbacks:
            f(x)
```

The property decorator is a neat way of allowing me to introduce callbacks where necessary without changing the class interface. However, after the third or fourth variable it's making the code a bit repetitive.

Is there a way to refactor this pattern into something along the following:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.var = 0
        enable_callback(self, 'var', 'var_callbacks')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to set the property on the class (since it is a descriptor), so using a `enable_callback` call in the initializer is not going to work.

You could use a class decorator to set the properties from a pattern:

```
def callback_properties(callbacks_attribute, *names):
    def create_callback_property(name):
        def getter(self):
            return getattr(self, '_' + name)
        def setter(self, value):
            setattr(self, '_' + name, value)
            for f in getattr(self, callbacks_attribute):
                f(value)
        return property(getter, setter)

    def add_callback_properties(cls):
        for name in names:
            setattr(cls, name, create_callback_property(name)

        return cls

    return add_callback_properties
```

Then use that as:

```
@add_callback_properties('var_callbacks', 'var1', 'var2')
class A(object):
    # everything else
```

Comment: You have a for loop after a return statement

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the [Python descriptor protocol](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/descriptor.html). In essence, you can define a class that handles the getting, setting and deleting of a property. So you could define a descriptor that runs your callbacks on setting the attribute.

Descriptors are regular classes, and can be parameterized. So you could implement a descriptor that takes the destination variable its constructor. Something like the following:

```
class A(object):
    var = CallbackDescriptor('var')
    foo = CallbackDescriptor('foo')
```